# How to sort a list of files by time, given only the filenames

Tags: command-line, filenames, sort

Given a list of file names, how can I sort it by file modification time?

The resulting output needs to look exactly like the input with the exception that the data has been sorted accordingly.

Here is a sample of the input.

```
/jobs/crm/import/done/20140227-1359-0009.txt
/jobs/bridge/open-workitem/done/20140227-1359-0009.txt
/jobs/bridge/opened-workitem/done/20140227-1359-0009.txt
/jobs/bridge/update-workitem/done/20140227-1401-0001.txt
/jobs/bridge/update-workitem/done/20140227-1403-0001.txt
/jobs/tfs/import/done/20140227-1401-0001.txt
/jobs/tfs/import/done/20140227-1403-0001.txt
/jobs/tfs/open-workitem/done/20140227-1359-0009.txt
```

Comment: Sort them by what?

Comment: There exists a command called `sort`.

Comment: Please show us an example input and desired output. DO you want to sort the names alphabetically or the files by modification date?

Comment: To sort by name, just use `sort`. Time etc would be more complex and need a script. Nobody can suggest anything without more information though.

Comment: Should it be sorted based on the modification time stored in the filesystem, or the timestamp in the filename?  Based on an earlier version of the question, I assume it's the file mtime, not the filename.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your input is small, and the file names don't contain spaces or other weird characters, you can just use `ls`.

```
ls -dt $(cat files)
```

`$(cat files)` puts the contents of `files` on the command line, and splits them on whitespace to get a list of arguments.  `ls -t` takes a list of files as its arguments, sorts them by mtime, and prints them.  `-d` is needed so it lists directories using their name, rather than their contents.

If that's not sufficient, you can try the [decorate/sort/undecorate pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform), e.g.

```
$ while IFS=$'\n' read file; do
    printf '%d %s\n' "$(stat -c +%Y "$file")" "$file"
  done <files | sort -k1nr | cut -f 2- -d ' ' >files.sorted
```

where `IFS=$'\n' read file; do ... done <files` sets `file` to each newline-delimited entry in `files` in turn, `printf...stat...` turns `<filename>` into `<mtime> <filename>`, `sort -k1nr` sorts lines based on the first field in reverse numeric order, then `cut` removes the `<mtime>`, leaving you with just `<filename>`s in sorted order.

Comment: The second solution is what I needed, since I had too many paths to exceed the max command-line length and also had paths with spaces in them.

Answer (score 2):

Perl has the '-M' operator for a file modification date.

This oneliner sorts files like required. The first line from top is the youngest file:

```
perl -e 'map { print "$_\n"; } sort { -M $a <=> -M $b } <*>'
```

or with a file list

```
perl -e 'map { print "$_\n"; } sort { -M $a <=> -M $b } @ARGV' $(cat files)
```

Comment: Very nice, +1! The one with the file list breaks on files with spaces though.

Answer (score -1):

Lets say your third party program is called producer.sh

then the following command will sort the files datetime part.

```
producer.sh | sed -e 's#/\([0-9].*$\)# \1#' |sort -i -k2|sed -e 's# #/#'
```

for reverse order

```
producer.sh | sed -e 's#/\([0-9].*$\)# \1#' |sort -r -i -k2|sed -e 's# #/#'
```

With your input, it produces

```
$ cat flist1 |sed -e 's#/\([0-9].*$\)# \1#' |sort -i -k2|sed -e 's# #/#'
/jobs/bridge/opened-workitem/done/20140227-1359-0009.txt
/jobs/bridge/open-workitem/done/20140227-1359-0009.txt
/jobs/crm/import/done/20140227-1359-0009.txt
/jobs/tfs/open-workitem/done/20140227-1359-0009.txt
/jobs/bridge/update-workitem/done/20140227-1401-0001.txt
/jobs/tfs/import/done/20140227-1401-0001.txt
/jobs/bridge/update-workitem/done/20140227-1403-0001.txt
/jobs/tfs/import/done/20140227-1403-0001.txt
```

Answer (score -4):

Assuming your input text stream consists of either fully qualified path names of files, or simply files in the same directory you issue the command, you can use the ls command with a couple of parameters to get the lastest timestamped files first by using the command ls where (listoffiles is the input):

```
$ cat listoffiles | ls -lt
```

In order to sort the listoffiles by size (5th column of ls -lt output and largest size first) instead of timestamp, the following command will suffice:

```
$ cat listoffiles | ls -lt | sort -rn -k5
```

Note1:  Just leave out the -rn parameter to get smallest size first

Note2: If the files are in the same directory, you can eliminate the preceding cat command in both of the above examples.

In order to separate all of the columns from the fully qualified path names of the listoffiles, I personally would use an nawk command to print out the column list of files in latest first timestamp order as follows:

```
$ cat listoffiles | ls -lt | nawk '{print $9}'
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. It is generally expected that you actually _test_ your answers before posting. Had you done so, you would have realized that `ls` cannot take piped input (what would be the point?) and that this answer does not work in the slightest. Also, even if `ls` _could_ accept piped input, your solutions would fail as on files containing white space or even on slightly different locales (think of how the date is displayed).

Comment: btw, we don't use BB tags as forums but markdown